# Why simple slideshow doesn't work?

Tags: javascript, html, css, slideshow

I just created this slideshow just to check if it works before I change it according to my own site but the slideshow just doesn't seem to work. The images are all displayed one below the other.

Here's the [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/526KK/)
Could someone please help me find out why it won't work? Is it something wrong with the way I linked it? Or maybe the code is wrong?

```
<script> 
var step = 1 
function SlideShow(){ 
  if(!document.images) 
    return document.images.MySlide.src = eval("image"+step+".src") 
  if(step<4) 
    step++ 
  else
    step=1 
  setTimeout("SlideShow()",1000) 
} 
SlideShow() 
</script>
```

I used this code as well but it still didn't work.

Comment: You really shouldn't use `eval`

Answer (score 1):

You have syntax error in your css class.

Instead of this

```
#slideshow {
    margin: 50px auto;
    position: relative;
    padding: 10px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
    width="600px";
    height="400px"
}
```

use this:

```
#slideshow {
    margin: 50px auto;
    position: relative;
    padding: 10px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
    width:600px;
    height:400px;
    overflow:hidden;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There are typo and syntax errors in your script.

```
$("#slideshow > div:gt(0))".hide();

setInterval(function () {
    $('slideshow> div:first')
        .fadeOut(1000)
        .next()
        .fadeIn(1000)
        .end()
        .appendTo('#slideshow');
}, 3000);
```

I've changed it to this:

```
$("#slideshow > div:gt(0)").hide();

setInterval(function () {
    $('#slideshow > div:first')
        .fadeOut(1000)
        .next()
        .fadeIn(1000)
        .end()
        .appendTo('#slideshow');
}, 3000);
```

**[WORKING SAMPLE](http://jsfiddle.net/526KK/2/)**

Comment: It still doesn't seem to be working for me. Maybe it's the way that I've linked the js sheet? [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Bmq2X/) These are the lines I used to link the sheets 
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Slideshow.css">
<script src="Slideshow.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

Comment: You didn't include the jQuery library in your fiddle.. You can find in the upper-left side labelled Frameworks&Extensions and select a jquery library

Answer (score 0):

I've corrected `some parts` of your code and it works [here](http://jsfiddle.net/526KK/1/).

Here is the original version of the code:

```
$("#slideshow > div:gt(0))".hide();

setInterval(function () {
    $('slideshow> div:first')
        .fadeOut(1000)
        .next()
        .fadeIn(1000)
        .end()
        .appendTo('#slideshow');
}, 3000);
```

And here is the corrected one:

```
$("#slideshow > div:gt(0)").hide();

setInterval(function () {
    $('#slideshow> div:first')
        .fadeOut(1000)
        .next()
        .fadeIn(1000)
        .end()
        .appendTo('#slideshow');
}, 3000);
```

**Corrections**

1. `$("#slideshow > div:gt(0))".hide();` => `$("#slideshow > div:gt(0)").hide();`
2. `$('slideshow> div:first')` => `$('#slideshow> div:first')`